# RecyclerView gets delayed to show up its items

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database

I am populating a `RecyclerView` from objects whose data is stored in a `Firebase` database. `RecyclerView` shows users who are currently using the app.
All the data is fetched correctly though `RecyclerView` does not show them up until the display turns off and turns on again. As soon as the display turns on back `RecyclerView` is populated with its items. I used debugging to find out the issue. While debugging it works perfectly. But when it comes to running the application, Issues comes back.If someone can help me to fix this highly appreciated.
I have posted my code below.

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mClient.connect();
    childEventListener = tempUserRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                UserDetailsClass userDetailsClass = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserDetailsClass.class);

                if (!userDetailsClass.getUserID().equals(UserDetails.getString("UniqueID", "ID"))) {
                    myFriendsAdapter.refillAdapter(userDetailsClass);
                }
                if (userDetailsClass.getUserID().equals(UserDetails.getString("UniqueID", "ID"))) {
                    sender = userDetailsClass.getName();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

Adapter Class

```
public class MyFriendsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyFriendsAdapter.MyFriendsViewHolder> {

Context context;
ClickListener clickListener;
List<UserDetailsClass> friendsList;

public MyFriendsAdapter(Context context, List<UserDetailsClass> friendsList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.friendsList = friendsList;
}

@Override
public MyFriendsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    MyFriendsViewHolder viewHolder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_online, parent, false);
    viewHolder = new MyFriendsViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyFriendsViewHolder holder, int position) {
    TextView name = holder.getName();
    name.setText(friendsList.get(position).getName());
    holder.getStateName().setText(friendsList.get(position).getStateName());
    setOnlineStatus(holder, position);
}

private void setOnlineStatus(MyFriendsViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (friendsList.get(position).getOnline_offline_status() == 1) {
        holder.getOnline_offline().setText("Online");
        holder.getOnline_offline().setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (friendsList == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return friendsList.size();
    }
}

public void refillAdapter(UserDetailsClass userDetailsClass) {
    friendsList.add(userDetailsClass);
}

public void cleanUp() {
    friendsList.clear();
}

public void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
}

class MyFriendsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView name;
    private TextView online_offline;
    private TextView stateName;
    private TextView distance;

    public MyFriendsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        online_offline = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.online);
        stateName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        distance = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView13);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public TextView getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(TextView name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public TextView getOnline_offline() {
        return online_offline;
    }

    public void setOnline_offline(TextView online_offline) {
        this.online_offline = online_offline;
    }

    public TextView getStateName() {
        return stateName;
    }

    public void setStateName(TextView stateName) {
        this.stateName = stateName;
    }

    public TextView getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(TextView distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (clickListener != null) {
            String name = friendsList.get(getPosition()).getName();
            clickListener.itemClick(view, getPosition(), name);
            //friendsList.get(getPosition()).getName();
        }
    }

}

public interface ClickListener {

    void itemClick(View view, int position, String name);
}

}
```

Comment: you forgot to call  notifydatasetchanged() after add

Comment: Sounds like an answer @ColdFire :-)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yeah it was one

Comment: @panduka pls accept the answer if it helped

Comment: @ColdFire Sorry for getting late to reply. It worked Perfectly and nicely. That was a huge help from you. Thank you very much.

Comment: @PandukaBupendra pls accept the answer by checking the checkmark left to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see you havent added  `notifydatasetchanged()` after the add method , you need to notify the adapter that you have added an item by that

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Either add it to here:

```
if (!userDetailsClass.getUserID().equals(UserDetails.getString("UniqueID", "ID"))) {
    myFriendsAdapter.refillAdapter(userDetailsClass);
    myFriendsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

or here:

```
public void refillAdapter(UserDetailsClass userDetailsClass) {
    friendsList.add(userDetailsClass);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void cleanUp() {
    friendsList.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use to populate list items in a RecyclerView with data from Firebase is to use a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. Check out these instructions for further information:

[FirebaseUI-database](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md)